# 形式，样式 and 方式 - appearance, style, form, shape...?

Tags: word-choice, usage, difference

In terms of the appearance of something, there a lot of HSK5 words that are very similar. Here are four and the definitions I've found thus far.

- 表面 - 1. surface (tangible, 方面 is intangible), 2. outside, appearance (表现 is more behavioural, subjective, the way something comes across)
- 形式 - n. outer appearance, form, shape
- 样式 - n. type, style
- 方式 - n. way, manner, style, pattern

Is there a clear way to distinguish between 形式，样式 and 方式? They all seem very close to each other and am not sure how to separate their usages.

Answer (score 2):

According to dictionary owned by Ministry of Education in Taiwan.

[形式](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000110674) can mean:

> 文學作品上指作品外在的體式。

(Format of literature.)

> 抽象或具體的事物，其形態的直接表現或組成。

(The way of how abstract or concrete things show directly or constitution.)

[樣式](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000157834) can mean:

> 樣子、形式。

(How does things look like, The way it show directly or constitution.)

[方式](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000036178) can mean:

> 說話或做事時所採行的一定方法、模式。

(The way of how to do things.)